# Unable to compile a C file in Contiki

Tags: c, random, contiki

I am trying to write a code in contiki that allows motes to randomly generate values.
Below is the code I tried:

```
#include "contiki.h"
#include "stdio.h" /* For printf() */
#include "stdlib.h"
PROCESS(random_process, "Random process");
AUTOSTART_PROCESSES(&random_process);
PROCESS_THREAD(random_process, ev, data)
{
PROCESS_BEGIN();
int r=rand();
printf("Hello, world. Random Number is %d",r);
PROCESS_END();
}
```

While generating the makefile I get the below error:

```
user@instant-contiki:~/Desktop/Random$ make target=native random_sample
TARGET not defined, using target 'native'
  CC        random_sample.c
  LD        random_sample.native
contiki-native.a(broadcast-annou): In function `set_timers':
/home/user/contiki-2.7/core/net/rime/broadcast-announcement.c:171: undefined reference to `random_rand'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [random_sample.native] Error 1
rm random_sample.co
```

Can someone please help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: OT: `#include "stdio.h"` --> `#include <stdio.h>`, same for `stdlib.h`

Comment: The error message refers to a function, `random_rand`, that's referenced in `broadcast-announcement.c`.  This is a linker error.  Presumably some library defines `random_rand`, but you haven't included it in your link command, which is why you're getting the error.  So, add it.

Answer (score 0):

You have not configured your project properly, you have to setup Makefile and project-conf.h to start with contiki, read the following hello-world example: http://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/tree/master/examples/hello-world.

I recommend you use the example in the link as a project start files.